# Error while trying to save User Input to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Whenever I try to save user input to a MySQL database, it saves empty rows as soon as I load the page. Here is my index.php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$uName = mysqli_real_escape_string(mysqli_connect($servername, $username, 
$password, $dbname), $_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string(mysqli_connect($servername, $username, 
$password, $dbname), $_POST['password']);

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES ('$uName', '$pass')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username"> <br> <br>
<input type="password" name="password"> <br> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Please tell me if there is anything I am doing wrong. 
Thanks

Comment: You should make _one_ connection to your database in the beginning. Then you use the same connection for each call. Right now, you're creating multiple connections; one every time you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and then one more after. That's _very_ bad for performance. You should also use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping and concatenating your queries.

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: The reason you get empty rows is because your script is attempting to store information from the `$_POST`-super global _on every request_, regardless if the form was posted or not. You should wrap that code in an if, to see if you got post data or not. Something like: `if (isset($_POST['username'],  $_POST['password'])) {  // Your DB code  }`

Comment: I would suggest that you rewrite your code according to the pointers I've given you before you continue with your script, or your application will be insecure. Security should always be priority one.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, I am new to PHP, and I wasn't actually trying to store passwords, that was actually only a test. Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: Also, I just figured out the problem. I declared the "conn" variable after mysqli_real_escape_string. So when I tried to run the program, it wouldn't know what conn is. I didn't what the problem was at the time, so I just copied and pasted everything that was in the "conn" variable. I didn't realize I needed to declare the variable at the beginning. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see modified code below:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$uName = mysqli_real_escape_string(mysqli_connect($servername, $username, 
$password, $dbname), $_POST['username']);
$pass = mysqli_real_escape_string(mysqli_connect($servername, $username, 
$password, $dbname), $_POST['password']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password)
VALUES ('$uName', '$pass')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username"> <br> <br>
<input type="password" name="password"> <br> <br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This code still have a bunch of issues: It's also creating three different connections to the database, when you only need one. It's also wide open to SQL injections and saves the passwords in clear text. I also fail to see the point of creating a database connection before the if-statement, since it's only used within the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $uName=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('$uName', '$pass')";
 if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
 {
    echo "New record inserted successfully";
 } 
 else 
 {
   echo "There have some problem";
 }

}
?>
```

Please Try this one

Comment: Warning! This code still have a few sever problems: it's still wide open to SQL injections and it saves the passwords in clear text! Those are _major_ security issues.